# Can someone explain this problem I am having with the proof of the Riesz-Fischer theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Here is the form of the theorem I have;

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in H$ be an orthonormal set (H a Hilbert space with inner product $(.,.)$) and let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $\mathscr{l}^2$. Then there exist $x\in H$ such that $a_n=(x,e_n)$ and $||(a_n)_1^{\infty}||_2=||x||$. (If in addition $\{e_n\}$ is complete then by proposition 5.24 $x=\sum_1^{\infty}a_ne_n$.)

I am confused about the last bit in brackets, can someone tell me what is wrong with this proof;

Suppose $m<p$, since $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in \mathscr{l}^2$ we have that;

$||\sum_{n=m}^pa_ne_n||^2 = \sum_{n=m}^p|a_n|^2 \rightarrow 0$ as m,p tend to infinity by Bessels inequality. This shows our sequence of partial sums is Cauchy in H and so converges to some element call it $x$ and so we may write;

$x=\sum_1^{\infty} a_ne_n$. Now for all $k\geq 1$ we have that;

$(x,e_k)=(\sum_1^{\infty}a_ne_n , e_k)=a_k$ by the definition of the inner product on H and clearly;

$||x||^2=||\sum_1^{\infty}a_ne_n||^2=\sum_1^{\infty}|a_n|^2$.

What is wrong with this? Why do we even need that last bit in the statement of the proof (in the brackets).

Comment: You have a typo in the second-to-last chain of equations, of course $(x,e_k) = a_k$, not $a_n$. Generally, you haven't said what $H$ is. I suppose it's a Hilbert space? (For otherwise, an $x$ with the desired properties need not exist.) Then I suspect the parenthetical is just badly phrased, and what is meant is that if $\{e_n\}$ is complete, then _every_ $x\in H$ has a representation $x = \sum a_n e_n$.

Comment: Sorry, H is a Hilbert space, yes all (.,.) is meant to represent the inner product and $\{e_k\}$ complete if for any $x\in H$ $(x,e_k)=0$ for all k means $x=0$

Comment: Yes, that $(\cdot\,,\,\cdot)$ is the inner product was clear. The point was that in an incomplete inner product space, such an $x$ generally doesn't exist, so it should be mentioned that $H$ is complete, i.e. a Hilbert space. As I said, I think the parenthetical is just badly phrased. For any Hilbert space $H$ and orthonormal family $\{e_n\}$ in $H$, you have an isometry $\psi \colon \ell^2 \to H$ given by $$(a_n) \mapsto \sum a_n e_n.$$ That isometry is surjective if and only if $\{e_n\}$ is complete.

Comment: Ok thats what I thought, so the completeness is only used in showing the surjectivity of the isometry you gave, and the Riesz-Fischer shows that it is well defined (and trivially injective). the bit at the end doesn't really need to be there? Is my proof right?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct. Whether the bit at the end needs to be there (albeit in different form) depends on what precisely the theorem statement is. I guess it is meant as a supplement to the first part (existence of $x$).